# SQL & SQL Server - Denormalized table, Distinct and Order By Complex Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-order-by, distinct

I've been working lately in this and I couldn't work it out. I have the following table:

```
ID      Language  Text
----    --------  --------    
1       spanish   Hola
1       english   Hello
2       spanish   Chau
2       english   Goodbye
2       french    Au revoir
3       english   Thank you
```

I need to get each ID once and the text in Spanish but if there wasn't any text in Spanish I should get the English one and so on.

So if I run this query I should get:

```
ID      Language  Text
----    --------  --------    
1       spanish   Hola
2       spanish   Chau
3       english   Thank you
```

I can not use

```
Select ID, Language, Text From table Where Language = 'spanish'
```

Because in the case there is no Spanish set I would not retrieve that ID and I need one record per ID. I though of maybe using something like this:

```
select Distinct(Id), Text from table 
order by FIELD(Language, 'Spanish', 'English', 'French', 'Italian')
```

But It didn't work. I get:

```
'FIELD' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks you all very much!

Comment: well, what's `FIELD()` supposed to do?

Comment: What do you want the query to return when there is no Spanish entry?

Comment: @Lamak . . . `field()` is a function in MySQL that is equivalent to `choose()` in SQL Server.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ah, MySQL, I'm an ignorant about it

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213236/sql-selection-of-best-rows/28213609

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another option:

```
SELECT i.ID, w.Text
FROM (
   SELECT ID  
   FROM Words
   GROUP BY ID) i(ID)
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT TOP 1 [Text]
   FROM Words
   WHERE ID = i.ID AND [Language] IN ('spanish', 'english')
   ORDER BY (CASE [Language] WHEN 'spanish' THEN 1                                 
                             ELSE 2
             END)
) w([Text])
```

For each ID contained in the `Words` table we perform a `CROSS APPLY` to find the matching `Text` that satisfies the criteria set by the OP.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly. Thanks you Girgos Betsos

Answer (score 2):

For this type of prioritization, you can use `row_number()`:

```
Select t.*
From (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by (case when Language = 'Spanish' then 1
                                               when Language = 'English' then 2
                                               else 3
                                          end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: How did it not work?  This is how I prioritize lists in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
select COALESCE(SP.id, EN.id, FR.id) as id,
       COALESCE(SP.Language, EN.Language, FR.Language) as Language, 
       COALESCE(SP.text, EN.text, FR.text) as text 
from (select disctinct id from table) as IDs
left join (select id, Language, text from table where Language = 'spanish') as SP on IDs.id = SP.id
left join (select id, Language, text from table where Language = 'english') as EN on IDs.id = EN.id
left join (select id, Language, text from table where Language = 'french') as FR on IDs.id = FR.id
where COALESCE(SP.id, EN.id, FR.id) is not null -- avoids null results for other languages (if there are)
```

This solution (or the equivalent replacement for `COALESCE`) works on any SQL variant I know

Comment: Nice approach! I didn't know the existence of COALESCE